# Displaying data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to learn a little bit of react
so I'm building this randon quote machine who gets the data from an API:

```
function App() {
 const [quoteData,setQuoteData] = useState({})
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => setQuoteData(data))
 },[])
```

My problem is when I'm tryin to display the quote by accessing it with quoteData[0].text
it gives me an error specifically Uncaught TypeError

Comment: You're initializing your state as an object,  but then setting it to an array. You'll need to show how you are accessing it, but on the first render `quoteData` will be an empty object so`quoteData[0]` will throw an error.

Comment: Try to check your quoteData on empty before render. Or you should add state isLoaded for example with false default value and set it true on load data.

Comment: - You need to set the initial value of quoteData as [ ].
const [quoteData, setQuoteData] = useState([])
- And for safety, 
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>{ Boolean(data) && setQuoteData(data)})
},[])